# Div not aligning

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am having trouble with the below CSS I cannot seem to get the white box to align next to the brands box:

[Live URL](http://pyro.agrilife.co.nz/)

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="homeWrapper">
            <div class="homeWrapperContentLeft">
        <div id="default">
            <div class="content_inner">
            <h1><span class="color_red">Welcome</span>/h1>
            <p>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="brands">
            <h1><span class="color_red">Products</span> by Brand</h1>
            <table class="manufacturer_table" height="24" style="width: 100%;" width="242">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
</tbody>
</table>

<div class="homeWrapperContentLeftCenter">
    text
</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>  
        </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.homeWrapperContentLeft{
    width:628x;
    height:825px;
    background-color: red;
}
.homeWrapperContentLeft .brands{
    float:left;
    width:251px;
    height:598px;
    padding: 12px; 
    clear: both;
}

.homeWrapperContentLeftCenter{
    float:left;
    width: 377px;
    height: 598px;
    background:#000;
}
```

Comment: black box? I don't see a white box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an invalid CSS at **custom.css** line **36**:

```css
.homeWrapperContentLeft{
    width:628x; /* should be px not x */
    height:825px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

And at line **32** you have given the width as `66px` to the wrapper. Please change that to `auto` or `100%`.

```
.homeWrapper{
    padding: 12px;
    width:66px;
}
```

---

The next thing is, you have this `.homeWrapperContentLeft .brands` class having a `float: left` and you have kept it in a very low width. Remove the `width` and `float: left;`.

```
.homeWrapperContentLeft .brands{
    float:left;
    width:251px;
    height:598px;
    padding: 12px; 
    clear: both;
}
```

---

Finally, take the `.homeWrapperContentLeftCenter` out of the `.brand`. This solves your issue.

Comment: good catch. not sure it solves his problem. it certainly make it more readable.

Comment: @iGanja Yeah, there are many more. I am just finding one by one and fixing them.

Comment: Thanks,  Still can't get why its not floating

Comment: @JessMcKenzie Now I have completed the answer. Please check all the points and make the changes.

Comment: My guess is he wants that black box next to the brands table. He's gonna have to change up his markup some to accomplish that.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I cant seem to get it to float - check the page

Comment: @JessMcKenzie Now it looks fine in Chrome... What do you expect now to happen?